# Can I install Linux on a computer that has Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, operating-systems

After installing Windows 7 on my computer that had Linux,Windows 7 erased everything that was part of Linux,including some games that I like. I doubt there is a way to recover those files. But,is there a way to install Linux and have 2 operating systems? (I saw that it js possible with multiple Windows os,being able to choose which to run in a selection screen,but I'm not sure if it works the same with Linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a linux version on a USB drive and restart your computer with the drive in the USB port.

Go to the BIOS menu, choose "Boot from USB" and follow instructions for Linux installation.

It comes with an option to be able to Dual Boot Windows and Linux, so choose that. You have the option to create a partition drive on your HDD for Linux.

Comment: I don't get the ">4GB" restriction. I've been using 4GB USB drive for the last few years and never had any problem with those... in fact I can usually use up to 1GB to keep files saved when using the drive as LiveCD.

Comment: You're right. Although, I do think there's a minimum space requirement on the linux live usb drive you choose.

Answer (score 6):

Of course. You can do it as a dual boot or using a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But I think you need to install GRUB instead of the Windows-Bootloader. It works fine for me. For recovering files you´ve got a great variety of programms (For example: Recuda). This works if you didn't override the deleted sector on your hdd. So try it. And for installing two system creating 2 partitions would be a good choice. You can create them during the most linux installations or at your windows installation. You can modify the size of the partition later so it isn't that important, but it should be enough to install at least your linux system on it. Using a USB-Stick as a live system works too and isn't that laborious, but slower.